# Creating an executable .exe file from a PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, executable

Is it possible to create an executable `file.exe` file from a PowerShell Script?

Answer (score 21):

No. At least, not yet, and after 5 versions of PowerShell, it seems unlikely ever.

I wish I could just leave it at that, but other people have provided a bunch of "workaround" type answers I feel compelled to address:

You *can* wrap your .ps1 script in another script type to make it double-clickable, and you can even generate an executable with the script embedded (see the other answers on this thread) ... but those "executables" require *the right version* of PowerShell to be already present on the system, so you're not gaining anything by doing that, and you loose a lot of the features of PowerShell (like streaming object output, help documentation, and automatic parameter handling with tab completion for users).

Here is a simple .cmd batch file wrapper (you could extend this to allow parameters):

```
REM <#
copy %0 %0.ps1
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -Command "&{Set-Alias REM Write-Host; .\%0.ps1}"
del %0.ps1
exit
REM #>

### Your PowerShell script goes below here.
### I've put a couple of lines as an example ...
ls | sort length -desc | select -first 5 | ft
ps | sort ws -desc | select -first 10 | ft
```

### I know ...

With **Portable PowerShell**, it would probably be possible to package up a sort of self-extracting zip that would contain the right version of PowerShell and a script and would work. That's **not** an executable in any normal sense of the word -- it's a bit like if Valve had decided to just ship a vmware image on a thumbdrive as their solution to letting Linux users play Half Life. However, the product seems abandoned.

With **PrimalScript** (or **PowerShell Studio**) or **PowerGui** or **pShellExec**, your script can be encrypted, so it's slightly secured against prying eyes ... but this is basically just obfuscation, and essentially no different than the batch file, and in some ways worse.

Comment: Similar solution using C is `#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File nameOfScript.ps1");
}`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a option with [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1) to create such `*.exe` Files.

#### Usage

The whole thing is really simple and well explained nevertheless
here is a snippet of it:

```
C:\Scripts\PS2EXE\PS2EXE_0.5.0.0.0\ps2exe.ps1 
    -inputFile  C:\Scripts\ExampleEXE\example.ps1 
    -outputFile C:\Scripts\ExampleEXE\example.exe -sta -noConsole -runtime40 -verbose -x64
```

---

*The only bad thing is that the project is depreciated. No Updates or new Versions since 2015.*

EDIT:
This projected has been picked up and is being maintained by a new person now.  You can find the updated code here, last updated 01/04/2018 as of this edit.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5

---

#### Version Information

For adding and editing the version information use something like [VERPATCH](https://ddverpatch.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home).

---

### UPDATE 2019

Shout out to a git-repo which is called [PythonEXE](https://github.com/jabbalaci/PythonEXE).

It demonstrates how to create an executable from a Python project and also provides a YouTube Step-By-Step Guide.

Comment: I did try this however it keep saying UNKNOWN VERSION OF POWERSHELL.

Answer (score 8):

Out of the box - no.  However I have built a PowerShell script that can take a script and create an EXE wrapper around it.  I created this script a while ago but decided to [blog it here](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/) for folks to check out.

Comment: Howdy Keith, Skydrive won't let me in, says is "not made for my browser", can you upload a .zip or create a mirror at pastebin / poshcode.  Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Use [PowerGUI's Script Editor](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/m/bits/20439049.aspx) (it is free and works).  Open your script in the PowerGUI Script Editor > Tools > Compile script > Choose whatever options you would like for your .exe (password protect source code, automatically close console after .exe runs, etc.).

Comment: This is also what the [PowerShell.org guys recommend](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/compile-ps1-to-exe/). Very easy.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Link dead.  At this time PowerGUI can be downloaded here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/Quest-PowerGUI.shtml

Comment: I am a big fan (and a seasoned user) of PowerGUI and I can see that this solution works fine for simple scenarios. However, it breaks where the PS code refers to a local path (looking for a config file  or execution log folder for instance). This shortcoming can be worked around but you need to be aware of it.

Comment: Although, PowerGUI is dead it lives on through Chocolatey! There are two ways to do it, use Chocolatey here(https://chocolatey.org/packages/PowerGUI) or look in the comments for a direct link to a Windows Live user provided link.

Answer (score 7):

I understood your question as "Can my PowerShell script generate an executable?"  That is what I was trying to do when I found this post.  That is possible using the Add-Type command.

```powershell
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) { 
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
"@ -CompilerParameters @{
    "GenerateExecutable" = $true
    "OutputAssembly" = "test2.exe"
}
```

Comment: More info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-to-write-a-console-application-in-powershell-with-add-type/

Comment: Thnx for the answer <3

Comment: I was about to post this myself, knowing someone might be looking for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found best to distribute a PowerShell script as exe was to wrap it in a [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net) executable.

I write a .nsi script like this:

```
Name "Maintenance task"
OutFile "maintenance.exe"
ShowInstDetails show

Section "Main"
  ;Executes the "script-to-run.ps1" PowerShell script
  InitPluginsDir
  SetOutPath "$pluginsdir\MyOrg" ;It is better to put stuff in $pluginsdir, $temp is shared
  ;extract the .ps1 and run it, collecting output into details.
  File script-to-run.ps1
  nsExec::ExecToLog 'powershell  -inputformat none -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "$pluginsdir\MyOrg\script-to-run.ps1"  '
  SetOutPath $exedir
SectionEnd
```

I just have to compile the script to an exe with the NSIS toolchain, and it will run on any OS that has PowerShell, no matter what is the execution policy.

This was inspired by this question [How to call PowerShell in NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13391340/11343).

Answer (score 2):

[PrimalScript](http://www.sapien.com/software/primalscript) from [Sapien](http://www.sapien.com) will generate an exe from a PowerShell script. The machine one which the executable is run must have PowerShell installed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project called Portable PowerShell that is still in beta after a couple of years ... might be worth looking at for your needs.

http://shelltools.wik.is/Portable_PowerShell