# How to call PowerShell in NSIS

Tags: powershell, nsis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run PowerShell in NSIS. when I run the NSIS script:

```
!include "x64.nsh"

Name "nsExec Test"

OutFile "nsExecTest.exe"

ShowInstDetails show

Section "Output to variable"

    nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -Command "& {Import-Module }" ServerManager'
    Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
    Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    DetailPrint '"ImportModules" printed: $1'
    DetailPrint "       Return value: $0"

    nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -Command "& {Get-WindowsFeature}" Desktop-Experience'
    Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
    Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    DetailPrint '"GetWindowsFeature" printed: $1'
    DetailPrint "       Return value: $0"
SectionEnd
```

When it executed to "Import-Module ServerManager", The PowerShell was started up(It can be seen in TaskManager processes). But nsExecTest.exe was hanging over.

I have googled this problem, and found a workaround for Java.
https://blogs.oracle.com/vaibhav/entry/not_as_easy_as_we

Anyone has ideas for this problem in NSIS?

Updated:
I simplify my test script.

```
!include "x64.nsh"

Name "nsExec Test"
OutFile "nsExecTest.exe"
ShowInstDetails show

Section "Output to variable"
${If} ${RunningX64}
    ${DisableX64FSRedirection}

    nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module ServerManager"'
    Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
    Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    DetailPrint '"ImportModules" printed: $1'
    DetailPrint " Return value: $0"
    DetailPrint ""

    ${EnableX64FSRedirection}
${Else}
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I found out, AaronLS's answer didn't work for me, I found two workarounds for this problem, related to a bug in PowerShell v2 [reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/572313/powershell-exe-can-hang-if-stdin-is-redirected#) (but never fixed):

- [Upgrade to PowerShell v3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx#BKMK_InstallingOnWindows7andWindowsServer2008R2)
- Run the script from a file in NSIS, and specify `inputformat none`. For a very strange reason you have to leave *two* spaces before the last quote of `nsExec::ExecToStack`:

  ```
  SetOutPath "$pluginsdir\NSISTemp"
  File script.ps1
  nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -inputformat none -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "$pluginsdir\NSISTemp\script.ps1"  '
  ```

Using the macros [I've written here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/PowerShell_support), it is just a matter of `${PowerShellExec} "echo 'hello powershell'"`.

Comment: I give up PowerShell, and use servercmd (it is replaced by PowerShell, but can still be used in Win2K8) instead at last.

Answer (score 2):

Been awhile since I used NSIS, so I'm just guessing based on syntax I saw elsewhere:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module ServerManager"'
```

Take out the second command, and just test with the first and get that working first, then you can be sure you have the first command right.

Also try adding `< NUL` to the end of your and/or my command line:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -Command "& {Import-Module }" ServerManager < NUL'
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module ServerManager" < NUL'
```

I'm not sure if it needs to be inside the double quotes or not.  It can hang if it's waiting for you to finish providing input as if you were running it interactively:

http://epeleg.blogspot.com/2010/06/solution-to-powershell-never-exists.html

Comment: I run the script like: `nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module ServerManager"'`. It prints errors "Access to the path is denied". I run `nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module ServerManager" < NUL'`, the same error. Could you please give me some advice on it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this command as well(your original command with < NUL added): `nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -Command "& {Import-Module }" ServerManager < NUL'`

Comment: Yes, I have tried my original command with < NUL also, and it returned the error: `Access to the path is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleHost.ReportException`

Comment: Only other thing I can suggest, is try getting the powershell command to work from a batch file first.  It might just be a matter of quotes placement with the < NUL.  Here is another work around for same issue but I don't understand the syntax at the end, but maybe it'll help you: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/572313/powershell-exe-can-hang-if-stdin-is-redirected#

Comment: Thank you, AaronLS. I haven't implemented this. It is hard to use powershell in NSIS. But your reply is very helpful.